# Wordpress Meta Box Form Data Not Saving

Tags: php, wordpress

My plugin is about adding FAQs to your desired page.

1. I have added a form within a metabox in the 'Add New Question'.
2. When I feed values in the form, the form data does save in
   the    database, but does not retain or show the values (selected)
   in the    form when the page updates/publishes.
3. Instead, the form shows the previous non-selected values (even though the
   selected values do    show up in the database).

---

```
<?php

function faq_manage_things($post)
{

global $post;
$post_id= $post->ID;
wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__),'faqs_questions_nonce');
$faq_stored_meta= get_post_meta($post->ID);

?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <p>
         <label for="meta-select" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Example Select Input', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></label>
            <select name="meta-select" id="meta-select">
                <option value="select-one" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-select'] ) ) selected( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-select'][0], 'select-one' ); ?>><?php _e( 'One', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></option>';
                <option value="select-two" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-select'] ) ) selected( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-select'][0], 'select-two' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Two', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></option>';
            </select>
    </p>

    <!-- TEXT AREA -->

    <p>
        <label for="meta-textarea" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Example Textarea Input', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></label>
        <textarea name="meta-textarea" id="meta-textarea"><?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-textarea'] ) ) echo $prfx_stored_meta['meta-textarea'][0]; ?></textarea>
    </p>


        <!-- CHECKBOXES -->

    <p>
        <span class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Example Checkbox Input', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></span>
            <div class="prfx-row-content">
                <label for="meta-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="meta-checkbox" id="meta-checkbox" value="yes" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-checkbox'] ) ) checked( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-checkbox'][0], 'yes' ); ?> /><?php _e( 'Checkbox label', 'prfx-textdomain' )?>
                </label>
                <label for="meta-checkbox-two">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="meta-checkbox-two" id="meta-checkbox-two" value="yes" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-checkbox-two'] ) ) checked( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-checkbox-two'][0], 'yes' ); ?> /><?php _e( 'Another checkbox', 'prfx-textdomain' )?>
                </label>
            </div>
    </p>


    </div>
<?php   
}

global $post;
function faq_meta_save( $post_id ) {
    global $post;
    $post_id= $post->ID;
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ); 
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'faqs_questions_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['faqs_questions_nonce'],basename(__FILE__)) )? 'true' : 'false';


    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) 
        {return;} //exit

    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-select' ] ) ) 
        {   update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-select', $_POST[ 'meta-select' ] );   }

    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-textarea' ] ) ) { 
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-textarea', sanitize_text_field($_POST[ 'meta-textarea' ]) );   }

    // Checks for input and saves
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-checkbox' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-checkbox', 'yes' );} 
    else {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-checkbox', '' );  }

    // Checks for input and saves
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-checkbox-two' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-checkbox-two', 'yes' );}
    else {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-checkbox-two', '' );  }

    }

    add_action('save_post','faq_meta_save');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if you have the meta_key duplicated in the database for the same post_id. Also, I recommend you to use underscores instead of hyphens in the meta_key names. Try this code where the meta_data of the post_id is deleted and then is added the new value.

Try this:

```
<?php

function faq_manage_things($post)
{

    global $post;
    $post_id= $post->ID;
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__),'faqs_questions_nonce');
    $faq_stored_meta= get_post_meta($post->ID);

    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <p>
            <label for="meta-select" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Example Select Input', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></label>
            <select name="meta-select" id="meta-select">
                <option value="select-one" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta_select'] ) ) selected( $prfx_stored_meta['meta_select'][0], 'select-one' ); ?>><?php _e( 'One', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></option>';
                <option value="select-two" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta_select'] ) ) selected( $prfx_stored_meta['meta_select'][0], 'select-two' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Two', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></option>';
            </select>
        </p>

        <!-- TEXT AREA -->

        <p>
            <label for="meta-textarea" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Example Textarea Input', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></label>
            <textarea name="meta-textarea" id="meta-textarea"><?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta_textarea'] ) ) echo $prfx_stored_meta['meta_textarea'][0]; ?></textarea>
        </p>


        <!-- CHECKBOXES -->

        <p>
            <span class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Example Checkbox Input', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></span>
            <div class="prfx-row-content">
                <label for="meta-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="meta-checkbox" id="meta-checkbox" value="yes" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta_checkbox'] ) ) checked( $prfx_stored_meta['meta_checkbox'][0], 'yes' ); ?> /><?php _e( 'Checkbox label', 'prfx-textdomain' )?>
                </label>
                <label for="meta-checkbox-two">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="meta-checkbox-two" id="meta-checkbox-two" value="yes" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta_checkbox_two'] ) ) checked( $prfx_stored_meta['meta_checkbox_two'][0], 'yes' ); ?> /><?php _e( 'Another checkbox', 'prfx-textdomain' )?>
                </label>
            </div>
        </p>


    </div>
    <?php   
}

global $post;


function faq_meta_save( $post_id ) {
    global $post;
    $post_id= $post->ID;
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ); 
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'faqs_questions_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['faqs_questions_nonce'],basename(__FILE__)) )? 'true' : 'false';


    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) 
        {return;} //exit

    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-select' ] ) ) {   
        remove_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_select', $_POST[ 'meta-select' ] );
        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_select', $_POST[ 'meta-select' ] );   
    }

    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-textarea' ] ) ) { 
        remove_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_textarea', sanitize_text_field($_POST[ 'meta-textarea' ]) );
        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_textarea', sanitize_text_field($_POST[ 'meta-textarea' ]) );   
    }

    // Checks for input and saves
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-checkbox' ] ) ) {
        remove_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_checkbox', 'yes' ); 
        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_checkbox', 'yes' );
    } 
    else {
        remove_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_checkbox');  
    }

    // Checks for input and saves
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-checkbox-two' ] ) ) {
        remove_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_checkbox-two', 'yes' );
        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_checkbox-two', 'yes' );
    }
    else {
        remove_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_checkbox-two');  
    }
}
add_action('save_post','faq_meta_save');
```

Comment: Well thanks for the help! But the small *bomb* was 'not saving the meta value of  $prfx_stored_meta above. So once I did that, it worked perfectly fine